# Convenience init not accessible for subclass if declared in extension Swift5.1 Xcode11.3

Tags: swift, swift5, xcode11.3, xcframework

```
    import UIKit

    public class MyButton: UIButton {}

    public extension UIButton {
        var someProperty: Int { 1 } // visible in xcframework

        convenience init(label: String) { // NOT visible in xcframework
            self.init()
        }
    }
```

I make xcframework. This code inside it. I link this xcframework to application and use it, but there is no convenience init for MyButton class. XCode 11.3

Answer (score 0):

Create `extension` of `MyButton` and not `UIButton`,

```
public extension MyButton {
    var someProperty: Int {
        return 1
    }

    convenience init(label: String) { 
        self.init()
    }
}
```

In application, access it using

```
MyButton(label: "Button_Label")
```

**Edit:**

Even if you subclass `MyButton`, `init(label:)` will be available in the subclass until you define its own initializers.

```
public class MySuperButton: MyButton {

}
```

You can access `init(label:)` in main project like,

```
MySuperButton(label: "Super Button")
```

Comment: What if once i will declare subclass of MyButton, for example MySuperButton, it will not have this convenience init.

Comment: @AlexeyNenastev You can access the `convenience init` in the subclass until you define subclass` own initialisers. I've edited the answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

The public flag is required in the convenience init. This will allows the init be visible in xcframework.

Try this

```
import UIKit

public class MyButton: UIButton {}

public extension UIButton {
    var someProperty: Int { 1 } // visible in xcframework

    public convenience init(label: String) { // NOT visible in xcframework
        self.init()
    }
}
```

However, you're updating the UIButton instead of your declared class MyButton. 
Make sure that is exactly what you want to do.

Comment: The whole extension is public. Marking ini(label:) as public explicitly is not required.

Comment: public flag did not help